# Is there any way to generate cheap proofs of Ethereum's state?

Tags: contract-development, protocol

A contract on the Ethereum network can interact with other contracts within it without requiring any proof, because the system itself defines methods for cross-contract communication (SEND, CALL). Interacting with an Ethereum contract from a different network, though, requires you to carry proofs of the state of the Ethereum network. Those proofs are expensive and hard to implement, mostly due to Ethash.

Is there any alternative, simple way to convince another network about the state of a contract on the Ethereum network?

Comment: In theory, you can construct a merkle proof that would be quite easy to verify; this is how light clients work. Unfortunately, I don't know of any simple libraries for generating these proofs.

Comment: But the merkle proof still require the other chain / light client to validate the whole sequence of block headers, which require ETHASH. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't read your question fully. No, there's no good way of proving things about the state if you don't have a reliable source of block hashes

Comment: I see - yet, I'm just wondering, couldn't zkSnarks or some similar "verifiable computation" algorithm be used to validate that "there is a sequence of blocks with accumulated work >= K, such that the final state is S"? If so, then the blockchain could just ask those compact proofs, instead of needing the whole thing.

Comment: It would be pretty hard to encode Ethash as a quadratic span program, so I don't know how practical zk-snarks would be. A better solution might be off-chain interactive proof verification a la Truebit

Comment: TrueBit still requires the whole data and programming the algorithm... but I guess that's what we can do :( thank you.